# JsonNode with Array elements

Tags: json, scala, jackson

The node fields contain an array. Currently there is only one element, So I can use `get(0)` to get the first element and parse the string to find the value of the valid.

The problem with this solution is if tomorrow there will be more k:v added to the array, this will fail. Also can I use any elegant way to parse the value of valid?

```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper}

  val response = """{"myTable":{"fields":["valid:true"]}}"""
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  val node = mapper.readTree(response)
  val result = node.get("myTable").get("fields").get(0).toString.contains("valid:true")
  println(s"valid=$result")
```

result :

`valid=true`

Comment: What do you expect `reult` to be if the array contain multiple items? And what did you try?

Comment: result should be same. i tried only till above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over array items using [elements](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#elements--) method. You just need to convert `Iterator` to `Stream`:

```
val fieldsValues = node.get("myTable").get("fields").elements()
val value = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(fieldsValues, 0), false)
  .filter(item => item.isTextual)
  .map[String]((item: JsonNode) => item.textValue())
  .map[Boolean]((item: String) => item.equals("valid:true"))
  .findAny()
  .orElse(false)
```

Comment: thank u .but .filter(item => item.isTextual) giving error.

Comment: i added these 2 libs import java.util.Spliterators
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport